# Can we use the Ibeacon with HTML5 webapp

Tags: web-applications, ibeacon

is there any reference showing the use of ibeacon with HTML5 web app.
i build a web app using HTML5 and javascript and i want to integrate ibeacon in my app.is it possible?

Thank you

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Important note**: The following answer was written with reference to the technologies the OP mentioned (HTML & JS). Specifically, I interpreted the question as "can I make use of iBeacons if I can only write HTML and JS?". It DOES NOT address the question of using iBeacons in a web browser. *You will have to create a native app to use iBeacon*.

**Update:** Since this answer was written, Google launched [Eddystone](https://developers.google.com/beacons/eddystone) which does have iBeacon-like capabilities and was supported by the Chrome browser. [This functionality seems to have been removed from Chrome](https://blog.beaconstac.com/2017/10/chrome-removes-physical-web-support-on-ios-android/).

---

Yes you can. This Cordova plugin can do it: https://github.com/petermetz/cordova-plugin-ibeacon It's not the most straight forward thing to get working but there is an example in the repo.

You can also take a look at http://evothings.com/ which can handle iBeacon functionality.

Good luck,
James

Comment: Note the Cordova page states: "Apps using Cordova are still packaged as apps using the platform SDKs, and can be made available for installation from each device's app store." which means they are not really a 'web app' to my understanding of what that means; they are a 'native app' which happens to have been developed in a way that leverages web app technology to make it easier to build for multiple native platforms

Comment: This answer is simply incorrect. Cordova, PhoneGap, React Native, will all enable you to use iBeacon because they are iOS applications, not websites. You cannot use iBeacon in the browser.

Answer (score 10):

It's not possible for an HTML5 web application running in a browser. You can access device native APIs through js by wrapping your webapp into an iOS or Android app using Phonegap or similar as James mentioned but that's it.

Answer (score -3):

Everything requires you to run it in the viewer, or compile it into a finished App. It's written in JS.

Comment: This isn't clear, and doesn't really answer the (bad) question.